# Wires on Arduino Mega 2560 rev3

Tags: arduino, wire

I wanna buy an Arduino but I don't know which wires you need for it and I need a wire that can transfer 5V. I mean the wires for the pins btw

Answer (score 0):

For prototyping you can use standard breadboard jumper wires. Like [these](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12795) from SparkFun.
They are rated AWG 28, so they can transfer up to [~200 mA](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm).

[image]